# Putting portable air conditioner hose in bucket of water

Tags: air-conditioning

Does it really work to use the hose to heat water in a bucket?    I do not want to leave my windows open at night for the hose to go outside.   I have heard the hot air from the portable air conditioner can be disposed of in this way.

Comment: No. Would either prevent air from flowing out the hose or would blow water all over. Make room hot and humid.

Comment: Do you have an exhaust hood over the stove that vents outside, i.e., not just recirculates?

Comment: If the heat stays inside (whether directly or heating water that then heats the room), you will defeat the purpose of the air conditioner. What is the reason for "do not want to leave my windows open at night"? If it is because the open window leaves open additional space next to the hose, take a piece of thick cardboard or other relatively stiff plastic or other material and cut it to match the size of the window opening and cut a hole in it for the hose.

Comment: You can put a clamp on the window track to keep it from being opened any further from the outside.

Answer (score 4):

This won't work in that simplified form. Even if the water did absorb a bit of heat as the air passed through, the water would heat up fairly quickly, at which point it would stop absorbing heat from the air. "Dissipation" doesn't mean "disappeared". The heat still exists somewhere. You'd have to change the water regularly. Also, you'd be adding moisture to the air via evaporation and possibly effervescence, countering the cooling effect of the air conditioner.

Now, if you wanted to split the airflow into many tiny tubes, provide a large quantity of cold water, and change the water regularly, it could work. Maybe. But probably not very well.

Comment: Keep in mind that the air conditioner probably does not have enough static pressure to force the air through the water in the first place.

Comment: Maybe. The vacuum created by the air's buoyancy might just overcome any backpressure.

Comment: >  "vacuum created by the air's buoyancy"
I don't follow?

Comment: I'm no fluid dynamicist, but the backpressure is created by the weight of the water column. Perhaps the buoyancy of the air as it is released from the hose counters that.

Comment: When the hose is placed in the water, the water will fill the inside of the hose up to the water line. The air pressure will have to displace that height of water, equivalent to about 0.5 psi per foot of submersion.

Comment: True. I hadn't considered that it's an open circuit.